# Checking if values in a column are a superset of another array

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this data as an example. I need to check which `a` values have all corresponding values of `b`. For example which `a` have all `[1,2]` corresponding `b` values.

```
In [1]:
    df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'], 'b':[1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2]})
    df

Out[1]: 
        a   b
    0   A   1
    1   A   2
    2   A   3
    3   B   2
    4   B   3
    5   B   4
    6   C   1
    7   C   2
```

So for this example i would like to return a list

```
    a
0   A
1   C
```

or

```
['A', 'B']
```

First I think i should generate a list of `b` values for every `a`

```
In [2]:
    df1 = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list).reset_index(name='b_list')
    df1

Out[2]: 
        a   b_list
    0   A   [1, 2, 3]
    1   B   [2, 3, 4]
    2   C   [1, 2]
```

Assuming this is the correct first step what should I do next?

**I would really appreciate solutions that only use the tools that `pandas` provides**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pivot table:

```
df.pivot('a','b','a').dropna(subset=[1,2]).index
```

Or use groupby:

```
df.groupby('a').b.apply(lambda x: set(x.tolist()).issuperset([1,2]))
```

or if you need it in a list:

```
(
    df.groupby('a')
    .b.apply(lambda x: set(x.tolist()).issuperset([1,2])).loc[lambda x: x]
    .index.tolist()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with lambda function:

```
df1.loc[df1.b_list.map(lambda x: set(x).issuperset(L)), 'a']
print (s)
0    A
2    C
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Anf for list:

```
a = df1.loc[df1.b_list.map(lambda x: set(x).issuperset(L)), 'a'].tolist()
print (a)
['A', 'C']
```

If use `issubset` solution is without lambda:

```
s = df1.loc[df1.b_list.map(set(L).issubset), 'a']
print (s)
0    A
2    C
Name: a, dtype: object

a = df1.loc[df1.b_list.map(set(L).issubset), 'a'].tolist()
print (a)
['A', 'C']
```